# Why is a return value of a method need not need be used sometimes?

Tags: java

I stumbled upon this problem, and could'nt seem to find a satisfactory answer to it. Consider the following line, in Java:

`ListBox.getValue(ListBox.getSelectedIndex())`

the `getValue()` method returns a String, but I haven't written it as

`String foo = ListBox.getValue(ListBox.getSelectedIndex())`

where the returned value is saved.

Why does writing the statement as in the first case does not cause a warning, or even an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can have a return value and a side-effect. Some purists don't like this but it's the way it is.

If you are only interested in the side effect but not the return value, you do not need to store the return value anywhere. (A "side effect" is where a function call causes the state to change).

In a language like Java that is garbage collected, the returned String will be garbage-collectable immediately although it will not be deterministic when the cleanup will actually happen. In C++ if you return an object as a "temporary" (like std::string) the object will be deleted immediately after the call (although you can bind it to a const-reference which retains its lifetime to that of the reference - the rare exception to when a reference can increase the lifetime of the object).

Comment: ohk, thats why all the fuss and hype behind functional languages.

Answer (score 3):

The returned value is "lost" as it doesn't get assigned to any variable.

Sometimes you just call a function for its side-effects and are not interested in the return value, hence, no warning.

Answer (score 1):

Examining that particular code:

```
ListBox.getValue(ListBox.getSelectedIndex())
```

I'm not familiar with Java GUI's, but would imagine that a ListBox may not have a selected index, in which case it will return a sentinel value such as -1.  If you call ListBox.getValue(-1), what happens?  A wild guess: it might throw an exception.  So, perhaps this code is effectively saying "if a selection hasn't been made in the listbox, thow an exception (I want to catch it elsewhere)".